# Join 3 tables up count the highest user in one table

Tags: mysql, database, join, count, inner-join

I'm trying 3 join tables so i can report who has the highest calls for each single customer please see the tables below

```
+-------+--+------------+
| users |  |            |
+-------+--+------------+
| id    |  | first name |
| 1     |  |  Bill      |
| 2     |  |  Ben       |
| 3     |  |  Bob       |
| 4     |  |  Barry     |
+-------+--+------------+
```

the second table is a call customers table

```
+-----------+--+-------------------+
| customers |  |                   |
+-----------+--+-------------------+
| id        |  | Company           |
| 1         |  |  windows company  |
| 2         |  |  glass company    |
+-----------+--+-------------------+
```

the third table is the where to calls are record

```
+-------------+--+--------+--------------+
| callrecords |  |        |              |
+-------------+--+--------+--------------+
| id          |  | userid |   company id |
| 1           |  |  1     |   1          |
| 2           |  |  1     |   1          |
| 3           |  |  1     |   1          |
| 4           |  |  2     |   1          |
| 5           |  |  2     |   2          |
| 6           |  |  2     |    2         |
+-------------+--+--------+--------------+
```

So as you can see in the call record table company id 1 which is the windows company has had 4 calls but user 1 made the most so that company i need to display bill company id 2 which is the glass company need to display user id 2 because they made 2 calls in total and not user id 1 because they only made 1 call

so the mysql query i need to make needs to loop round so the report looks like this

windows company - most calls bill
glass company - most calls Ben

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: please give us a clear display of your expected output, and try to improve the explanation because it's wordy, garbled and poorly formatted (in fact it's not formatted at all, there isn't even any punctuation, and so it's hard to read and comprehend, when it needn't be). Also, have you tried to write anything in connection with this already? Normally we expect that we'd see an example of your efforts explaining what problem you've run into while attempting it, rather than just asking others to solve it on your behalf, in their spare time, for free...

Comment: ...we're happy to _help_ people, less happy to _replace_ people. It's a Q&A service, not a free write-my-code service. But I can't see a question here, just a set of requirements. "I need" is not a question, it's a demand.

Comment: Show us what have you try. And what problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single query that will fetch records. You can check below query. This will give you highest calls for each single customer.

```
SELECT CR.companyid, C.company, U.first_name, COUNT(CR.userid) AS callCount
FROM callrecords AS CR
INNER JOIN customers AS C ON (C.id= CR.companyid)
INNER JOIN users AS U ON (U.id= CR.userid)
GROUP BY C.id,CR.userid  HAVING callCount = (
    SELECT count(callrecords.userid) as count
    FROM callrecords
    WHERE callrecords.companyid = CR.companyid
    GROUP BY callrecords.userid
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Ignore spells of table or column name because table's or column's name in question is not well formatted.